# Why is my for loop being ignored?

Tags: python, dice

```
import random
stats = [0]*6
fixed = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
def single_roll(n,fixed=(),sides=6):
    for x in range(0,n):
        dice = random.randint(1,6)
        if dice == 1:
           stats[0] += 1
        elif dice == 2:
           stats[1] += 1
        elif dice == 3:
           stats[2] += 1
        elif dice == 4:
           stats[3] += 1
        elif dice == 5:
           stats[4] += 1
        elif dice == 6:
           stats[5] += 1
x = list(zip(fixed, stats))
single_roll(10)
print (x)
```

When I try and run this, why does it produce a list with 0's for the stats list? Why is my for loop not being used in the program? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating `x` before calling your `single_roll` function, and at that point the `stats` list is all zeroes. `stats` is used to compute the value of `x`, but afterwards `x` is a brand new list with no connection to `stats`, so even though `single_roll` modifies `stats`, `x` doesn't change. You can just put the assignment after the call:

```
single_roll(10)
x = list(zip(fixed, stats))
```

Comment: Just beat me to it ;)

Comment: Another syntax question : Is there any way I can put my stats and fixed functions after my def line instead of before it?

Comment: @Zach2095 You could if you want, but every time you call the function, it would make the `stats` list go to a list of zeros. It would depend on what you are trying to  achieve.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is this:

```
import random
stats = [0]*6
fixed = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
def single_roll(n,fixed=(),sides=6):
    for x in range(0,n):
        dice = random.randint(1,6)
        if dice == 1:
           stats[0] += 1
        elif dice == 2:
           stats[1] += 1
        elif dice == 3:
           stats[2] += 1
        elif dice == 4:
           stats[3] += 1
        elif dice == 5:
           stats[4] += 1
        elif dice == 6:
           stats[5] += 1


single_roll(10)      
x = list(zip(fixed, stats))  #place this after the function call
print (x)
```

Now this will output:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2), (5, 2), (6, 1)]
```